# Prove that monotone functions are equal

Tags: definite-integrals, monotone-functions

Suppose that $f,g$ are both monotone functions on $[0,1]$ such that for every $b\in[0,1]$:

$$\int _0^bf(x)dx= \int _0^bg(x)dx $$
Prove / disprove : $f(x)=g(x)$ for every $x\in[0,1]$

I’m pretty sure it’s true since I proved a more general theorem in measure theory, However, I am struggling to find a basic proof to the monotone case using basic arguments.

Answer (score 1):

What about $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=1$ otherwise and $g$ the constant function equal to $1$?

Or $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=1+x$ otherwise and $g(x)=1+x$ for $x \in [0,1]$ if you wish to have strictly increasing maps.

Comment: This one actually works… the theorem I was talking about was said the functions are equal almost everywhere… Thanks